# reCAPTCHA Enterprise Returned "Requests from this referrer are blocked"

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I am trying to create an assessment using an API key in recaptcha enterprise.

Setting HTTP referer restriction on API key returns "Requests from this referer are blocked" and does not work.

I looked at the documentation and set it up as follows 
・example.com/* 
・*.example.com/*

If HTTP referrer restrictions are removed, a score is returned.

What could be the reason for this error?

My English is not very good, but I'll be happy if we can understand each other.

Thank you.

I also tried the following domains. 
・https://example.com/* 
・https://*.example.com/*

Answer (score 0):

I also spent more time than I had planned with this...

It worked when I added the referer header with the host of the request url of my action.